# why can't I initialize a static const pointers with other static const pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, static, initialization, constants

Im not entirely sure whether or not the following brakes the C standard, but clang allows one to initialize static const `scalar` typed variables with the contents of another static const `scalar` variable, example:

```
static const long temp = 10;
static const long temp1 = temp;
```

when I try with pointers, it fails.

```
static const long *const temp = (void *)1000; // ok
static const long *const temp2 = (void *)&temp2; // ok
static const long *const temp1 = temp; 
// ^^^^ error: initializer element is not a compile-time constant
```

one way to over come this would be to simply use long or any other scalar type large enough to hold addresses ...

```
static unsigned long long temp;
static const unsigned long long addr = (unsigned long long)&temp;
static const unsigned long long addr2 = addr;
```

this sounds horrible not to mention Im not entirely sure how safe it is, since I don't know if the linker/loader can/will update addresses ...

any ideas as to how or even if it is possible to initialize a static const pointer with the contents of another static const pointer ... to be more precise I was trying with function pointers, but noticed the same thing with other pointer types ...

Comment: You'd have to use defines instead of static consts.

Comment: well that depends on your definition of `variable` and which temp specifically you are referring to, some compilers seem to be smart enough to detect static const scalar types and replace them with immediates, so I was wondering why can't it do the same thing with const *const pointers, (readonly pointers, src address and dest value) ...

Comment: @PavelŠimerda yes I've being using macros though lately I've being trying to see if their are any other methods, macros can be quite taxing at compile time, and brutal on most IDEs ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the text covering this:

C11 6.6/7:

> More latitude is permitted for constant expressions in initializers. Such a constant expression shall be, or evaluate to, one of the following:
>
> - an arithmetic constant expression,
> - a null pointer constant,
> - an address constant, or
> - an address constant for a complete object type plus or minus an integer constant
>     expression.

C11 6.6/9:

> An *address constant* is a null pointer, a pointer to an lvalue designating an object of static
>   storage duration, or a pointer to a function designator; it shall be created explicitly using
>   the unary **&** operator or an integer constant cast to pointer type, or implicitly by the use of
>   an expression of array or function type. The array-subscript **[]** and member-access **.**
>   and **->** operators, the address **&** and indirection ***** unary operators, and pointer casts may
>   be used in the creation of an address constant, but the value of an object shall not be
>   accessed by use of these operators.

C11 6.6/10:

> An implementation may accept other forms of constant expressions.

So, your `temp` does not qualify to be an *address constant* because it doesn't satisfy any of the options in the definition of address constant.

**Rationale:** IDK, it seems like an oversight to me. Perhaps it is to avoid placing undue burden on the compiler; e.g. if `(void *)1000` does not actually point to an object (e.g. it points outside the process's address space, or is a trap representation), then evaluating `temp` causes undefined behaviour (no diagnostic required).

**Workaround:** Using `unsigned long long` is not as good as using `uintptr_t`. However ,

```
static const long *const temp1 = (void *)1000;
```

seems like a better option than the integer options. You could use a `#define` macro to avoid repeating the actual address.

Comment: interesting, whats a `an address constant`? does `&temp` qualify as an address constant or do they mean a literal/immediate ...

Comment: @SamyVilar my second quote starting "An address constant is" explains what an address constant is.  `&temp` qualifies because it is "a pointer to an lvalue designating an object of static storage duration, created explicitly using the unary `&` operator".

Comment: doesn't temp, evaluate to a constant address, ie it was initialize with a constant address so doesn't it evaluate to a constant address and can be used as such or am I misinterpreting things ... I guess my question would be "does c have constant address type?"

Comment: +1 You may find it interesting to examine the same series of operations using variables [without static linkage](http://ideone.com/UiwShy) (i.e. local automatic vars in a function).

Comment: @SamyVilar no it doesn't

Comment: Still I'm not sure how safe this approach is if/when the linker does symbol relocations ... I should add that I'm trying to avoid macros, or rather looking for another approach, since most decent compilers will do literal replacement with static const variables, I've used macros extensively so much so that I've had to abandon some IDEs cause they would crash ...

Comment: @SamyVilar if you're talking about how safe `(void *)1000` is , that's entirely up to the compiler. The compiler documentation should describe how it handles casting it to pointer.

Comment: @WhozCraig interesting, Ill take that route assuming the compiler is smart enough to collapse the variables to immediates or at the very least not actually allocate anything on the stack or do any actual initialization at entry point ...